# how can I fix imports in my crawler script?

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to use relative imports in subfolder `crawler` to import utility from `common`?

Of note, if I move the script into the root folder it works – but I need to call common.utils from scripts , how can I fix this?

```
├── crawler
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── utils.py 
│   ├── collector.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── test_imports.py # ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
│   │   └── update_importer.py



test_imports.py

from .common.utils import fimct1 # error or from crawler.common.utils import fimct1 the same
print(fimct1)
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing an `__init__.py` in the project root.

Comment: it's below collector or where you mean?

Comment: In `crawler`...

Comment: you mean outside of crawler project?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. `test_scripts.py` is under `scripts`, so your import would expect that tree:
`crawler -> scripts -> common -> utils`

Use `crawler.common.utils` instead. Or, if you still want to go with relative imports, try `..common.utils`. But, to be honest, relative imports aren't a good idea.